# I am making a interactive console program

Tags: c#

I'm working on a interactive console application that waits for user input and then parses it through a switch statement using a interface called `IConsoleCommand` and I'm curious how I can pass parameters through to the command class objects.

```
    static IConsoleCommand Parse(string input)
    {
        var parts = input.Split(' ').ToList();
        var command = parts[0];
        var args = parts.Skip(1).ToList();

        switch (command)
        {
            case "exit":
                return new ConsoleCommands.Exit();
            default:
                return new ConsoleCommands.Unknown();
        }
    }
```

full example:https://gist.github.com/e-r-o-s/03e6997f54d3882eee113f10323707bd

Comment: give the commands constructors that take arguments

Comment: This looks suspiciously like an assignment.   Now there is no problem of that so long as you say so and make an attempt.  I doubt you wrote the code above

Comment: the above code in a previous stack overflow question and im trying to implement it into a personal project. the problem I had trying to do so is modifying the interface would I have to implement seperate methods in the interface that take parameters or is there another way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to modify the Interface. As user @Nkosi mentioned, give the commands constructors that take arguments like so:

```
class ConsoleCommands
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Exits the program.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Exit : IConsoleCommand
    {
        private List<string> _arguments;

        public Exit(List<string> arguments)
        {
            _arguments = arguments;
        }

        public bool Run()
        {
            // TODO: Utilize _arguments list so that Run method uses them
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unknown command.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Unknown : IConsoleCommand
    {
        public bool Run()
        {
            ConsoleWriter.Red.Line($"{Message.COMMAND_UNKOWN} ");

            return true;
        }
    }
}

static IConsoleCommand Parse(string input)
{
    var parts = input.Split(' ').ToList();
    var command = parts[0];
    var args = parts.Skip(1).ToList();

    switch (command)
    {
        case "exit":
            return new ConsoleCommands.Exit(args);
        default:
            return new ConsoleCommands.Unknown();
    }
}
```